# Looking to grab data from an API and have it build a table using Node/Express

Tags: node.js, api, express, ejs

I'm looking to build a crypto price web app like www.coincap.io or www.coinmarketcap.com ; I initially started hard coding with EJS and then realized this would take forever.

This is the code I have thus far, and I'm wondering what I should throw into the forEach loop to have my javascript build a table for me as it receives results. Any ideas?

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    request("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=100", function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            data.forEach(function(prices){

            })      
            res.render("index", {data: data});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've found a jQuery plugin called Tabular that I think should do the trick, but still kind of confused on how to integrate this into an express/node app.

Comment: got it working all good. Highly recommend Tabulator for JS tables. Such good docs/information and devs are great about responding and helping